# How can I chain cases in Bash 3.2, which doesn't have `;&`?

Tags: bash, case, centos5

I have a bash script that resumes aborted execution with a case statement. It works great with Bash 4 under CentOS 6 but does not work with CentOS 5 because of Bash 3.2.

Is there any programming logic I can use to replace the following with something more "portable"?

```
last-action=$(cat /tmp/last-action)

case last-action in)
    beginning)
    function1
    ;&
    middle)
    function2
    ;&
    end)
    function3
    ;&
esac
```

The thing is, wherever task execution stopped it must resume there and execute everything that comes after. For example, if `last-action=middle` it would execute `function2` and then `function3`. That's where the operator `;&` came in handy.

Any clues to do this without a lot of `if` statements?

Comment: use `ksh`? Good luck.

Comment: Actually ksh works for this, but then a lot of my other functionnality does not work anymore. I'll really have to stick with bash i guess.

Comment: if tou want to add 1 or 2 examples about that to your question, I'd be interested to know know. My experience writing med-complex to work in ksh or bash, I only found 1 or two issues where I felt I was a major differencce. Good luck.

Comment: My project is located on [https://github.com/deajan/osync](https://github.com/deajan/osync) and well, it won't even run with ksh  because certain double quotes which are sometimes 2 or three times escaped. Btw i have already setup a (bad programmed) workaround for the above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand that fallthrough is very convenient, but given your example snippet I don't see how

```
case "${last_action}" in
        beginning)
                function1
                function2
                function3
                ;;
        middle)
                function2
                function3
                ;;
        end)
                function3
                ;;
esac
```

would add much overhead to your code. It's still prettier than lots of `if`s.

However, if your switch is more complex and you want this to be more dynamic, you can do something along the lines of:

```
#!/bin/bash

function1() { echo 1; }
function2() { echo 2; }
function3() { echo 3; }

last_action=$1

actions_beginning="function1 function2 function3"
actions_middle="function2 function3"
actions_end="function3"

_actions="actions_${last_action}"
for action in ${!_actions}; do
        "${action}"
done
```

```
$ ./test.sh beginning
1
2
3
$ ./test.sh middle
2
3
$ ./test.sh end
3
```

EDIT: Just looked at your code on github and I myself would definitely go this route.